# Parse out XML data into Rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am trying to parse WordPress data in our SQL Server from an Elasticsearch structure.

This is the contents of one field on one record;

```
<category domain="category" nicename="featured">Featured</category>
<category domain="post_tag" nicename="name1">Name 1</category>
<category domain="post_tag" nicename="name-2">Name 2</category>
<category domain="post_tag" nicename="different-name">Different Name</category>
<category domain="type" nicename="something-else">Something Else</category>
```

I'd like to parse this out as a table with the headers Domain, NiceName and Contents and a row for each of these nodes in the data. Something along these lines;

| Domain | NiceName | Contents |
| --- | --- | --- |
| category | featured | Featured |
| post_tag | name1 | Name 1 |
| post_tag | name-2 | Name 2 |
| post_tag | different-name | Different Name |
| type | something-else | Something Else |

The number of nodes is different for each row in the data and can appear in any order. Currently the data is stored in a varchar data type but this can be modified if it's best to parse using something like XML.

Comment: If you are storing XML, you should be using the `xml` data type. You can't parse XML as XML if it isn't `xml`.

Comment: Is there a question here? Have you tried reading the SQL Server documentation around the [nodes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type) and [value()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) XML methods?

Comment: I'm aware that this should be stored as XML. As mentioned, I can change the data type on the field. I can't for the life of me work out how to parse out the XML into separate rows. I could add my attempts in here but the question would be 3 times as long, I thought that being succinct would be beneficial here. The question is: how do i parse out this XML to produce the data table I supplied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommended that you use the `xml` data type for storing XML data. But if you must store it in a `varchar` column you can use `try_cast` to cast it to XML (which results in `null` if it's not actually valid XML) and then work with it using the normal [`nodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type), [`query()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type) and [`value()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) XML methods such as the following...

```sql
create table dbo.Records (
  OneField varchar(max)
);
insert dbo.Records (OneField) values
  ('<category domain="category" nicename="featured">Featured</category>
<category domain="post_tag" nicename="name1">Name 1</category>
<category domain="post_tag" nicename="name-2">Name 2</category>
<category domain="post_tag" nicename="different-name">Different Name</category>
<category domain="type" nicename="something-else">Something Else</category>');

select
  Category.value('@domain', 'varchar(50)') as [Domain],
  Category.value('@nicename', 'varchar(50)') as [NiceName],
  Category.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as [Contents]
from dbo.Records R
cross apply (select try_cast(OneField as XML)) X(OneFieldXML)
cross apply OneFieldXML.nodes('/category') N(Category);
```

| Domain | NiceName | Contents |
| --- | --- | --- |
| category | featured | Featured |
| post_tag | name1 | Name 1 |
| post_tag | name-2 | Name 2 |
| post_tag | different-name | Different Name |
| type | something-else | Something Else |